# Pygame, inheritance issue

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance, pygame

I am either new nor experience in python and i find myself in a fat problem that even after many hours in Google and Bing i can find the answer for. My problem starts with this code:

```
    class Rectangulo(object):
    def __init__ (self, x, y, color, largo, alto, cambio_x, cambio_y):
        self.alto = alto
        self.largo = largo
        self.color = color
        self.cambio_x = cambio_x
        self.cambio_y = cambio_y
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def dibujar(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(pantalla, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.alto, self.largo))
    def mover(self):
        self.x +=  self.cambio_x
        self.y +=  self.cambio_y

class Elipse(Rectangulo):
    def __init__(self):
        Rectangulo.__init__(self)
        def dibujar (self):
            pygame.draw.ellipse(pantalla, Rectangulo.color,(Rectangulo.x, Rectangulo.y, Rectangulo.alto, Rectangulo.largo))
```

THis is the most important piece of code right now. I have find the problem laid in Elipse and have tried many ways to make the inheritance to work, but the console continue showing this message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josh/Escritorio/Codigo python/Jueguito.py", line 63, in <module>
    miEl = Elipse(x,y,VERDE,alto,largo,cam_x,cam_y)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 8 were given
```

Everytime i tried to call the class function dibujar() with this code:

```
for item in range(10):
    x = random.randrange(685)
    y = random.randrange(485)
    alto = random.randrange(20, 71)
    largo = random.randrange(20, 71)
    cam_x = random.randrange(1, 2)
    cam_y = random.randrange(-3, 3)
    miObjeto = Rectangulo(x,y,VERDE,alto,largo,cam_x,cam_y)
    miLista.append(miObjeto)
    miEl = Elipse(x,y,VERDE,alto,largo,cam_x,cam_y)
```

miEl variable used to have their own for loop but i thought in this way would be less confusing for me. I still can't figure out what is happening. I fear i need some help.

Comment: This is why most programmers use English for variable names...

Comment: I did it in spanish because the tutorial was in spanish so i just followed the pace. But i can traduce if it's really a bother for you.

Comment: Your constructor for `Elipse`  is `def __init__(self)`, but you are passing it 7 parameters. You need to specify them.

Comment: So should i place something like  def __init__(self, x, y, color, blah, blah)? I tried that already and it doesn't work

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josh/Escritorio/Codigo python/Jueguito.py", line 63, in <module>
    miEl = Elipse(x,y,VERDE,alto,largo,cam_x,cam_y)
  File "/home/josh/Escritorio/Codigo python/Jueguito.py", line 22, in __init__
    Rectangulo.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', 'color', 'largo', 'alto', 'cambio_x', and 'cambio_y'
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Eclipse` instance is failing to initialise, because when it calls the initialise of its base class `Rectangulo`, *that* class takes 7 parameters (x, y color, ... etc) and you aren't providing any.

So you have a number of options, but the two  most common approaches would be:

- Pass the same 7 params into `Eclipse`'s `__init__` method, and then pass those same params into the call to `Rectangulo.__init__(self, ...)`
- Decide on the params to be used for the `Rectangulo` within the `Elipse` e.g. `Rectangulo.__init__(self, 1, 2, "red", ...)`.

Generally speaking you will probably want the first option. e.g.

```
class Elipse(Rectangulo):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, largo, alto, cambio_x, cambio_y):
        Rectangulo.__init__(self, x, y, color, largo, alto, cambio_x, cambio_y)
```

If your Elipse class needs no additional parameters of its own, then you can simplify the above a little by doing this:

```
class Elipse(Rectangulo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Rectangulo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This will basically pass any and all arguments given to the instantiation of Elipse through to the `Elipse.__init__` call.

Comment: THanks, it worked like a spell. The program is working again thanks to you.

Comment: Great, if you can accept the answer that would be appreciated!

Comment: I apologize by my noobity, but how do i do that?